# Grails autowire inside Spring converter

Tags: grails

I have something like this...

```
class DomainConverter implements GenericConverter {
    private Class<Domain> classOfDomain;
    private Class<DomainCommand> classOfDomainCommand;
    public Set<GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair> getConvertibleTypes() {
        Set<GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair> convertiblePairs = new HashSet<GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair>();
        convertiblePairs.add(new GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair(classOfDomain, classOfDomainCommand));
        convertiblePairs.add(new GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair(classOfDomainCommand, classOfDomain));
        return convertiblePairs;
    }
    public Object convert(Object source, TypeDescriptor sourceType, TypeDescriptor targetType) {
        if (classOfDomain.equals(sourceType.getType())) {
            return this.convert((Domain) source);
        } else {
            return this.convertBack((DomainCommand) source);
        }
    }
    protected DomainCommand convert(Domain definition){
        ...
    }
    protected Domain convertBack(DomainCommand command){
        ...
    }
}
```

Do I have to wire it within the class or add it to the resources.groovy?

How do I create the DomainCommand so that I still have my autowiring

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert) you can see an example of bean declaration:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>

<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <list>
            <bean class="example.MyCustomConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So you need to declare your converter and also the conversionService in your `resources.groovy` file.

Comment: Pretty much right on but I would recommend doing this in the groovy like you hint out file instead. instead (that is how I ended up doing it). XML files are a bit old school :-)

Comment: Yeah, I just pasted the Spring version so you could translate it to the Groovy DSL version.